# Extend validity of a OpenVPN certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, openvpn

I have an openvpn server, clients authenticate using ssl certificates. Whenever a client certificate expires, a new certificate must be issued and sent to the client.

I've found that easyrsa from openvpn has a **renew** command but AFAIK does not really renew: [Easyrsa "renew" is a misleading name · Issue #345 · OpenVPN/easy-rsa](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/issues/345)

So question is: is technically possible extend the validity of a ssl certificate regardless if it's expired or not in order to avoid sending a new file to the client user?

Comment: renew should be generating a new cert, with the same key, renew would not extend the cert itself and no you can't change the end date on a cert unless you have the private key of the issuing certificate authority...to which would be renewing it.

Comment: As I understood the question the both CA key and cert is available. The "problem" is related to "skip" the distribution of the new cert to the client... And once you have key&cert of the CA the "new" cert request could be created from the existing (even expired) cert so issuing of the new (following) certificate is not the issue from technical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

This is very nice question :-).

```
Technically : yes (at the end the client could use expired one to connect)
Easily : no
```

In principle it is not possible as CA sign the cert request with specific time of validity so it cannot be extended. What you can do it create new certificate and the tricky part could be in the process of issuing and in the process of checking the validity.

**At the beginning it would be fair to mention that following stuff is technically related to certificates in general and I didn't test it with openvpn - if it would not pass the overall answer would be NO :-(.**

In openVPN configuration there are 3 parameters related to certificates - ca, key and cert.

- key : private key for the data signing. Can be used for decrypting the data encrypted by the **cert**.
- cert : public key (derived from **key**) to confirm the validity of the data signed by the key. It can be used for encrypting the data for the key. This would be provided to the "other end" during secure connection negotiation. / this scenario works with the case that valid cert could be already known on remote end so sending the cert may be optional and provided expired one could be ignored /
- ca : It is used to check the validity of the cert provided during secure connection negotiation.

Once the client cert is expired the case is that just **cert** is outdated. The key in principle is not expiring and CA should not be expired (in that case it is totally different use case ;-) ). Cert contain validity period and it is part of "envelop" signed by the CA in x.509 structure.

It is good practise to generate new key with generating new cert but there is nothing forcing this step so technically it is not problem to create CSR (Certificate Signing Request) using the same key like actually expiring certificate. In case you have available old CSR you can use it directly for new cert. Once this CSR is signed with CA the new cert is derived from the "old" key.

The tricky part is that you need (one of):

- deliver this new cert to current user to replace the cert
- get know the server about this certificate so it can be used instead of expired one provided by the client (this is the theory part on this use case ;-) )

What I know is that you can combine more CA certs in **ca** file linked in the configuration on server without issue (in PEM format). Technically "user" cert and "ca" cert differs in parameter saying if it could be used as CA. So technically you can combine CA cert with this newly generated cert into one file...

Once this file will be in place (the most probably restart of openvpn server will be needed) you can try to establish new connection. Once the client with the key would try to connect it may happen that the server will be able to "identify" the key based on hash paired with this client cert located on server and ignore the certificate provided by the client (this have to be tested). Technically (point of view of certificate as technology) it would work but I didn't try it with openVPN. As openVPN is using external library for SSL stuff it may be working approach ;-).

On client side is needed CA to proof the server side (this is not expired), key to sign and decrypt the communication (this is not expired) and own cert is not really needed for local operation so expired one is not really an issue. The cert of the server is get during SSL negotiation and checked using local CA cert so all needed is available (local key, remote cert).

The cons of this approach is that you are a little bit loosing benefit of CA as single cert for client cert validating (you need to have it listed on server side next to CA cert) but on the other side the plus would be possibility of renewing the cert...

In case you will try it feel free to provide feedback...

Good luck!

---

The other approach in case of planning could be issue long validity range certificate and utilise CRL (Certificate Relocation List) to revoke non valid cert during the time. But this is not a scope of this question...

Comment: While searching also for initial question I found this thread and I must say that from your  explanation you have a bigger logical problem with certificates and you should improve your knowledge to answer such questions ;-)
1) 
> In principle it is not possible as CA sign the cert request with specific time
> of validity so it cannot be extended.
Even this sentence is right it has nothing to do with the question / need for a renew of the CERTIFICATE itself ?

Comment: @Reiner030 I think my understanding of the certificate topic is quite good ;-). I agree you cannot extend validity of already issued certificate. But the question was mainly related to "in order to avoid sending a new file to the client user". My logical construction was about how to renew the cert but utilize already delivered key. New cert, which is related to the existing key (from "old" certificate), is handled just on server side so on user's side you can use old key (which is not expiring) with exp. cert (which is ignored). New cert is "paired" on server side.That was question about ;-).